# Routing iPhone audio from bluetooth input to default output (not bluetooth)

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am working on a project that requires almost live (we can live with some core audio latency) audio monitoring from a bluetooth microphone to the iPhone's default

I've tried both:

```
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
OSStatus stat = AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput, sizeof (allowBluetoothInput), &allowBluetoothInput);
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
stat= AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof (audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);
```

and

```
UInt32 overrideAudioRoute = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof (overrideAudioRoute), &overrideAudioRoute);
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

but neither yields the correct behavior

Is there any property I can set to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about a speak through application? I did some R&D on this awhile back and ran into the issues you are talking about. At the present it seems that this is not possible on iOS. You cannot configure your iPhone to record from the microphone and route that audio recording out to the speaker for instant playback. The best you can do is record it, stop it and send it. Recording and playing through the speaker cannot be configured in an audio session. Spending time researching this (like I did) will be upsetting. It has nothing to do with core audio hacking it has to do with what is allowed by the system